# How to do the same without using Ext.getCmp in this code?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

This is the code im using and im firing button click event once the window show event is called. this works fine. but how to do the same without using Ext.getCmp

this is the line

```
Ext.getCmp('recent_refresh').fireEvent('click');
```

this is the code

```
 Ext.create('widget.window', {
      title: 'Activity',
      closable: true,
      closeAction: 'hide',
      width: 250,
      height: 300,
      bodyBorder: true,
      tbar: {
          xtype: 'toolbar',
          ui: 'plain',
          items: [{
              iconCls:'refresh',
              id: 'recent_refresh',
              listeners: {
                click: function(){ 
                      Ext.Ajax.request({
                          url: 'control.php',
                          params: {
                              'case': '18'
                          },
                          success: function(response){
                              var json =  Ext.decode(response.responseText);

                          }
                      });               
                }  
              }
          },
          '->',
          {
              xtype: 'displayfield',
              name: 'act_date',
              id: 'act_date',
              value: new Date(),
              formatValue: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d')
          }]
      },      
      layout:'accordion',
      border: false,
      items: [ grid1, grid2, grid3 ],
      listeners: {
            show: function() {      Ext.getCmp('recent_refresh').fireEvent('click'); }        
      }

}).show();
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  One way is to make an assignment with the Ext.create call since Ext.create returns such a reference.  The app namespace in the example below is a filler since any namespaces you are using are unknown from your text.  Once you have the variable reference to the widget, you can get use it to get a reference to the top toolbar and then get a reference to the item you want inside of the toolbar.

```
    Ext.ns('app');
    app.activityWin = Ext.create('widget.window', {...}
    app.activityWin.getTopToolbar().get('recent_refresh').fireEvent('click');
```

Comment: thanks for reply. any other way to do this? i want to fire this click event inside the window listener

Comment: Why are you looking for another way?

Comment: this.getTopToolbar().get('recent_refresh').fireEvent('click');

Comment: getting error getTopToolbar() is not a function, anyway found a way to do this  this.down('#recent_refresh').fireEvent('click');

Comment: note that in Ext JS 4 tbar bbar are discouraged.  dockedItems with dock: 'bottom' or doc: 'top' is the recommended way to defined toolbars in a pane. [link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-dockedItems)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ref` property.. I don't know if it has been carried forward to Ext JS 4, but here's how we do it in Ext Js 3.3

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
..config..
buttons : [{
  text : 'save'
  ref : 'saveButton'
}],

listeners : {
  show : function(win){
   win.saveButton.fireEvent('click'); //saveButton here is the same as used in ref above.
  }
}
});
```

`ref` can now been used directly and no need to use `Ext.getCmp`

check the correct usage of ref in your case and implement it..

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. will check this way too